# ServerSocket и SSL handhake между клиентом и моим "сервером RDP"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, rdp

Необходимо имитировать работу RDP сервера (процесс авторизации через NLA), для этих целей был использован компонент `TServerSocket`. Клиент при подключении устанавливает подключение по протоколу TCP, далее после успешного подключения клиент (Стандартная программа от Windows "Удаленный рабочий стол") посылает HEX последовательность используя протокол RDP. В этой последовательности указаны данные о поддерживаемых режимах подключения. Ниже представлена сама последовательность и ее расшифровка.

```
Client: (RDP пакет) Клиент рассказывает что умеет
03 00 00 13 0E E0 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 08 00 03 00 00 00
 03 -> TPKT Header  TPKT version = 3
 00 -> TPKT Header  Reserved = 0
 00 -> TPKT Header  Packet length - high part
 13 -> TPKT Header  Packet length - low part (total = 19 bytes)
 0e -> X.224  Length indicator (14 bytes)
 e0 -> PDU Type  CR Connect Request (Тип PDU  запрос подключения CR)
 00 00 -> X.224  Destination reference = 0
 00 00 -> X.224  Source reference
 00 -> X.224  Class and options = 0

 01 - Тип пакета (Запрос на переговоры RDP)
 00 - Флаги (нету)
 08 00 - размер пакета, должен быть установлен в 8 байт (сейчас правильно)
 03 00 00 00 - То что поддерживает клиент (на данный момент TLS и CredSSP)
```

В ответ на этот запрос сервер посылает аналогичную последовательность со своими режимами работы. После отправки этого пакета сервером у клиента появляется диалоговое окно авторизации (NLA)

```
Server: (RDP пакет) Сервер рассказывает что умеет
03 00 00 13 0E D0 00 00 12 34 00 02 0F 08 00 02 00 00 00
 03 -> TPKT Header  TPKT version = 3
 00 -> TPKT Header  Reserved = 0
 00 -> TPKT Header  Packet length - high part
 13 -> TPKT Header  Packet length - low part (total = 19 bytes)
 0e -> X.224  Length indicator (14 bytes)
 d0 -> X.224  Type (high nibble) = 0xd = CC TPDU; credit (low nibble) = 0
 00 00 -> X.224  Destination reference = 0
 12 34 -> X.224  Source reference = 0x1234 (bogus value)
 00 -> X.224  Class and options = 0

 02 -> Тип пакета (должен быть установлен в 02, сейчас правильно) (Ответ на переговоры RDP)
 0F -> Флаги. Поддерживаются блоки расширенных клиентских данных, поддерживается протокол расширения графического конвейера, поддерживается режим ограниченного администрирования (Вроде для NLA)
 08 00 -> Размер пакета, должен быть установлен в 8 байт (сейчас правильно)
 02 00 00 00 -> Выбранный механизм защиты информации. Выбран CredSSP (Для NLA авторизации)...
```

Далее после ввода авторизационных данных клиентом передается HEX последовательность с SSL хендшейком (Client Hello) для установки защищенной передачи данных. Мне расшифровать и использовать данную последовательность не удается. Прошу помочь в решении вопроса, я так понимаю есть в Delphi 7 компоненты поддерживающие OpenSSL, возможно ли корректно интегрировать компонент? и укажите пожалуйста где подробно описан механизм обмена ключами в документации к протоколу RDP. [Ссылка](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-RDPBCGR/[MS-RDPBCGR]-170316.pdf)

Все что удалось узнать о этой последовательности:

```
Client: (TPKT пакет) Судя по всему с хендшейком
16 03 01 00 7e 01 00 00 7a 03 01 59 94 8b 0f ad d6 ca 7e 6b da de 6f 38 ea 49 2e 32 d6 31 17 9c 73 76 31 99 7f ff 91 b0 e3 66 23 00 00 18 00 2f 00 35 00 05 00 0a c0 13 c0 14 c0 09 c0 0a 00 32 00 38 00 13 00 04 01 00 00 39 00 00 00 13 00 11 00 00 0e 32 31 33 2e 32 32 31 2e 32 31 35 2e 32 30 00 05 00 05 01 00 00 00 00 00 0a 00 06 00 04 00 17 00 18 00 0b 00 02 01 00 00 17 00 00 ff 01 00 01 00
 16 -> recordType=handshake
 03 01 -> sslVersion=3.1 TLS 1.0
 00 7e -> recordLength = 126
 01 -> handshake.msg_type = ClientHello
 00 00 7a -> handshake.length = 122
 03 01 -> handshake.client_version = 3.1 TLS 1.0
 59 94 8b 0f -> handshake.random.gmt_unix_time = 1502907151 = 16 Aug 2017 18:12:31 GMT
 ad d6 ca 7e 6b da de 6f 38 ea 49 2e 32 d6 31 17 -> handshake.random.bytes
 9c 73 76 31 99 7f ff 91 b0 e3 66 23 -> непонятно что
 00 -> handshake.session_id (0 for no re-used session)
```

Попытки дальше расшифровать пакет и прочие действия не увенчались успехом, прошу помощи в установке нормального соединения и передачи авторизационных данных между клиентом и моим "сервером RDP"

Comment: За документацию спасибки, пытался найти - впервые вижу.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать сокетный шлюз сокетом перенаправить пакеты на MS RDP (для этого нужно 3 компа) и наблюдайте пакеты. Может увидете больше.

Comment: Попробуйте пока сделать режим "без шифрования".  Если можно укажите номер страницы где вы взяли информацию по структуре, или хотя бы дайте те имена которые в приложеном PDF. Врядли быстро найдётся тот кто разобрал RDP протокол, но спустя год может быть.

Comment: `handshake.random.bytes` скорее всего ключ для SSL либо соль, либо и то и другое.

Comment: nick_n_a, незачто. Режим без шифрования не применим т.к. в этом случае NLA не будет работать, нужно именно CredSSP. Впринципе начинаю понимать суть обмена ключами. Информация подробнее где более менее описана структура и суть: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_SSL.html и еще: https://tls.dxdt.ru/tls.html Думаю не год это продлится а 1-2 дня, благо после долгого поиска кое-что нашел)

Comment: Страницы из PDF где разбор пакетов: 319, где описание 1-2 пакетов: 39.

Comment: Еще 1 ссылка по теме SSL http://blog.fourthbit.com/2014/12/23/traffic-analysis-of-an-ssl-slash-tls-session

Comment: Я нашел как на плюсах подключить SSL, думаю порт на делфи - не сложен. Если вопрос ещё актуален. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1175861/17974 Пока не пробовал RDP расшифровать используя SSL. О, на enSO появилось https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200210/rdp-communication-via-c-c