# Как установить соединение с сайтом по HTTPS из программы на C++?

Tags: c++, ssl, https

В ответ на GET запрос через 80-й порт сайт отвечает 301-м кодом и отправляет на защищённую страницу. Как добиться от него 200-го кода? Знаю, что есть общепринятая openssl, но я в принципе не знаю что с ней делать и какие функции в каком порядке вызывать, так как с https на уровне ниже javascript (где всё на автомате) не работал, а надо из windows-приложения соединиться с сайтом по защищённому протоколу.

Подскажите пожалуйста порядок действий.

Comment: возможно это поможет https://stackoverflow.com/a/40270207/690987

Comment: Какая ОС у вас?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, работаю в Вин10, но приложение должно работать на любой винде, начиная с висты

Comment: @Iceman тогда можно даже без cURL, только через WinAPI

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать библиотеку curl, она вполне умеет переходить по цепочке редиректов и поддерживает https, если собрана с openssl (вроде он нужен). При этом нет необходимости дергать методы openSSL руками и библиотека работает на разных ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Для windows.

Из всех библиотек, я нашел ту, которая коннектится через secur32.dll.
Идея проста, secur32 даёт вам АПИ из 10-функций для шифрования, вы АПИ даёте пакет - АПИ пакет шифрует так как надо, потом отправляете пакет в сокет. Так и работаете Программа<->secur32<->socket. В сокет отправляете и забираете програмно. Я за 8 часов смог переписать под свои нужды.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000189/A-Working-TCP-Client-and-Server-With-SSL (нужна регистрация через мейл)

Я бы отметил, что для "минимального" приложения, библиотеку можно "перетрусить". Я оставил ф-ции Initialize, SSPINegotiateLoop,   CreateCredentials, GetNewClientCredentials, RecvPartialEncrypted, Recv, Send.

Подключив два файла - можно уже пользоваться библиотекой.

Пример работы с ней (минимальный пример, фрагменты)

```
char msg[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\Host:address.my\r\n\r\n";
x->Initialize("address.my",0,0);
x->Send(msg,sizeof(msg));
x->Recv(buff,sizeof(buff),sizeof(buff));
```

Обратить внимание на   `dwSSPIFlags |= ISC_REQ_MANUAL_CRED_VALIDATION; // Разрешить непровереные сертификаты`

Я урезал библиотеку до 1000 строк. Я так думаю что даная библиотека позволяет делать ssl соидинение не только для https, но и для других ssl протоколов.

Вот, очень похоже на рабочий пример
http://cpdn.cryptopro.ru/content/sspi/html/group___web_example_SSPIClient.html